# Minify/Uglify javascript snippet on browser

Tags: javascript, minify, uglifyjs

I want to minify/uglify JavaScript snippet on browser.
I tried uglify js or many others.But everyone has dependency of fs module.
So I am getting fs module not found.

Any help on this.?
Please remember i dont want to use webpack, grunt etc.I just want to minify
small snippet at run time.

Comment: what's the goal?

Comment: I am generating small javascript snippet code dynamically and i need to minify and uglify that snippet at run time.Snippet always different so i cant minify in early stage.

Comment: but why minify on the client? What's the goal?

Comment: A quick google search found me this, which provides an API: https://javascript-minifier.com/

Comment: Sorry but looking for client side solution. Don't have time to do API call for this.As there might be 10-20 javascript snippet at a time.Thanks

Comment: Minifying code is an exercise to improve the performance of fetching scripts from the server. If they're already fetched from the server and loaded in memory, there's no reason to minify.

Comment: I am already using webpack and doing everything with my bundle(minification , concatination etc etc).But this is the strange use case i got.

Comment: you should try to define/clearify why you need to minify a script since it is already on the client? You will realise that there is no reason at all to do that and, additionally, each client should minify the code...

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://www.npmjs.com/package/terser , confirm it will work for your purpose, (example, it's being used for this [javascript minifier tool](https://iotools.cloud/tool/javascript-minifier)).

You can load Terser in your application like this:

```
const { minify } = require("terser");
```

Or,

```
import { minify } from "terser";
```

Browser loading is also supported:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/source-map@0.7.3/dist/source-map.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/terser/dist/bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Then use async high level function, `async minify(code, options)`. Example:

```
var code = "function add(first, second) { return first + second; }";
var result = await minify(code, { sourceMap: true });
console.log(result.code);  // minified output: function add(n,d){return n+d}
console.log(result.map);  // source map
```

It's also mentioned here in another Stack Overflow question here [Minify and compress js code snippet in react (client side)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75661338/minify-and-compress-js-code-snippet-in-react-client-side)