# Minify and compress js code snippet in react (client side)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, compression, minify, uglifyjs

I need to minify and compress a code snippet string to be sent to the sever and i'm using UglifyJs for that, But there's two problems with this approach.
First that UglifyJs doesn't support Es6+ code and i'm getting error from minification result when i run this code:

```
import { minify } from "uglify-js";
const { code, error } = minify(`asyc function() {...});
```

the `error` is:

> Unexpected token: keyword (function)

The solution for this seems to be `uglify-js-es6` package which makes UglifyJs compatible with Es6+.

The other problem is that UglifyJs isn't compatible with browser (in my case react) because of `fs` usage, the error is:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users...'

The solution for this is `uglifyjs-browser` package.
Now the actual problem is that i don't know how to use these two packages in merge to handle my case, in the `package.json` file `uglify-js` is the Es6+ compatible version:

```json
{
    ...,
    "uglify-js": "github:mishoo/UglifyJS2#harmony",
    ...,
}
```

But `uglifyjs-browser` is still not working. Actually it should not because `uglifyjs-browser` is compatible with `UglifyJsv3` and `uglify-js-es6` with `UglifyJsv2`!
The other solution that i tried was to convert es6 to es5 via Babel, but it didn't work cause of `fs` usage in Babel.

Any help on this? is there any other solution or package to minify code snippets in client side?
Thank you.

Comment: Paste some code along with the error message you are getting to be able to help

Comment: @Parvez Thank you, i made some changes, please check.

Comment: I think you want to `build` your react app and then uglify the result of the build not the actual code in your project.

Comment: @LarsVonk No i'm somehow making and IDE and the code will run on server, it would be a real big string (e.g. 200 lines of code) so i want to compress it before sending to server via API. My problem is about code strings not a part of my own program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like uglifyjs-browser is no longer supported, try using [Terser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/terser), to minify code client side as it is in active development. I used it, to check if it works in the browser: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-shadow-7pey78?file=/src/index.js . Seems like it does work well as a minifier/compressor.